# Binaries from postgresql not available when linked to another docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to do something very simple: Call `psql` or any other Postgrsql binary from within a container that links to it. For instance, doing something like:

`docker run --name my_build -i -t --link=postgres my_image /bin/bash`

Assuming of course that `postgres` container is running. Any idea why `my_image` does not have those binaries included? This is part of a CI pipeline, in which the `my_image` does in fact have access to Postgresql, but for some reason not to its commands directly. Am I missing something here?

I also tried `volumes-from`, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well I assume that the postgres binaries are installed in the postgres container, but no on my_image. And you are trying to call those commands from the my_image container. The docker link is only a network link, just allow to connect to the linked container by any port. Also put in /etc/hosts the container name and its ip to easy the connection.

If the binaries are installed in my_image, check how to tell them issue a remote connection to the postgres container.

Regards